# ATL(atlalloc.h) generates errors while compiling

Tags: c++, visual-c++, atl

The compiler rises a couple of errors while compiling my code.
Errors:

```
Error   1   error C2039: 'AtlThrowImpl' : is not a member of 'ATL'  e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\atlalloc.h  184
Error   7   error C2039: 'AtlThrowImpl' : is not a member of 'ATL'  e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\atlalloc.h  184
Error   11  error C2039: 'AtlThrowImpl' : is not a member of 'ATL'  e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\atlalloc.h  184
Error   16  error C2039: 'AtlThrowImpl' : is not a member of 'ATL'  e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\atlalloc.h  184
Error   22  error C2039: 'AtlThrowImpl' : is not a member of 'ATL'  e:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\atlalloc.h  184
```

This is the code part of the header:

```
    template <typename T>
inline T AtlThrow(T tLeft, T    tRight)
{
    T tResult;
    HRESULT hr=AtlAdd(&tResult, tLeft, tRight);
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        AtlThrow(hr);
    }
    return tResult;
}
```

My question: How can i repair this errors from the header? Do i need to install some sdk's or something about ATL?

Answer (score 2):

There is something in your code which excludes `AtlThrowImpl` from compiler input:

- you somehow exclude `<atlexcept.h>`
- or, you have `_ATL_NO_EXCEPTIONS` defined
- or, you have `_ATL_CUSTOM_THROW` defined
- or, you have `__ATLEXCEPT_H__` defined other then by including `<atlexcept.h>`

`AtlThrowImpl` is in atlexcept.h, having full project in front of you you can check what exactly conflicts and excludes it.

Comment: Can you give me a link from where i can download all atl's headers?

Comment: ATL is shipped with MS Visual Studio, excluding free Express versions. There is no download link. A cut of pretty old ATL is freely available with DDK.